# Can I run Ubuntu 64-bit on a Dell PowerEdge 2650?

Tags: dell, 64-bit, 32-bit, versions

I have downloaded both the 32bit and 64bit iso's and tried to install ubuntu on a Dell PE2650. Both times the install stops telling be I need the i686.

I'm new to Linux and confused, any help would be greatly received...

Answer (score 1):

The PowerEdge 2650 is [not a 64-bit CPU](https://serverfault.com/questions/74499/poweredge-2650-is-it-64-bit-capable) and Ubuntu itself only supports 64-bit CPUs since 2017 of last year. You have two options:

- You can run an older version of Ubuntu like 16.04 selecting on of the [i386 builds](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/). Note that these packages won't really be supported anymore.
- You can run [Debian](https://debian.org) which Ubuntu is based on which still has 32-bit support.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Kristophers answer... Look in to other Debian subproject distros that support 32 bit machines like Kubuntu, Lubuntu, or Xubuntu.